# Minimum swaps required to convert a series into AP

Tags: algorithms

Lets say i have a sequence ${6, 10, 11, 16, 17}$. Each number represents number of coins. The task is to find the minimum swaps to convert the sequence into AP 
Lets say common difference is $3$.
To convert into AP, I'll do the following

Take one coin from $10$ and give it to $11$.
one from $16$ and give it to $17$.
So I will get the AP sequence with 2 swaps.
I can transfer more than one coin in a single swap.

My Approach:
First I will find a sequence with the given common difference. 
Considering the above sequence, its sum is $60$.
So, $60=\frac{5}2*(2a+(5-1)*3)$
On solving, $a=6$

So creating the AP sequence, $6, 9, 12, 15, 18$

Subtracting this sequence with the above sequence, 
we get $[0, -1, +1, -1, +1]$ 
I want to convert all the elements to zeros.
First I'll sort this sequence 
$[-1, -1, 0, +1, +1]$
I'll point the first element and the last element by left and right respectively and find the sum.

If the sum is -ve then change *right to $0$ and *left to obtained sum.

If the sum is +ve then change *left to $0$ and *right to obtained sum.

If the sum is $0$, change *left and *right to $0$ and increment left and right.

At each step increment the count.

Loop will terminate when left>=right.

The final count is the answer.

I am not sure of the correctness of the algorithm.

Is there any recursive solution to it?

Comment: What exactly is your question?  When you ask "How can I find this?", what is the "this"?  Note that we discourage "please solve this exercise for me" and "please check whether my solution to the exercise is correct" questions.  You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: thanks for the change. I mean to find a recursive solution